# What exactly does tf.expand_dims do to a vector and why can results be added together even when matrix shapes are different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, matrix, addition

I'm adding two vectors that I thought were 'reshaped' together and getting a 2d matrix as a result. I expect some type of error here, but didn't get it. I think I understand what's happening, it treated them as if there were two more sets of each vector horizontally and vertically, but I don't understand why the results of a and b aren't different. And if they're not meant to be, why does this work at all?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

start_vec = np.array((83,69,45))
a = tf.expand_dims(start_vec, 0)
b = tf.expand_dims(start_vec, 1)
ab_sum = a + b
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    a = sess.run(a)
    b = sess.run(b)
    ab_sum = sess.run(ab_sum)

print(a)
print(b)
print(ab_sum)
```

=================================================

```
[[83 69 45]]

[[83]
 [69]
 [45]]

[[166 152 128]
 [152 138 114]
 [128 114  90]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, this question makes more use of **broadcasting** characteristics of tensorflow, 
 which the same as numpy ([Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)). `Broadcasting` gets rid of the requirement that the operation shape between tensors must be the same. Of course, it must also meet certain conditions.

> General Broadcasting Rules:
>
> When operating on two arrays, NumPy
>   compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing
>   dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible
>   when
>
> 1.they are equal, or
>
> 2.one of them is 1

A simple example is one-dimensional tensors multiplied by scalars.

```
import tensorflow as tf

start_vec = tf.constant((83,69,45))
b = start_vec * 2

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(b))

[166 138  90]
```

Back to the question, the function of `tf.expand_dims()` is to insert a dimension into a tensor’s shape at the specified `axis` position. Your original data shape is `(3,)`. You will get the shape of `a=tf.expand_dims(start_vec, 0)` is `(1,3)` when your set `axis=0`.You will get the shape of `b=tf.expand_dims(start_vec, 1)` is `(3,1)` when your set `axis=1`.

By comparing the rules of `broadcasting`, you can see that they satisfy the second condition. So their actual operation is

```
83,83,83     83,69,45
69,69,69  +  83,69,45
45,45,45     83,69,45
```

Comment: Hey @giser_yugang, I've been playing with TensorFlow since asking this question and I registered the two rules of broadcasting that you mentioned above. But the other day, I needed to multiply two tensors element-wise, shapes [20, 50, 36, 42] and [20, 50]. I reshaped the second one to [20, 50, 1, 1] then used tf.broadcast_to to broadcast it up to [20, 50, 36, 42] so that I could multiply it. But it turns out that for the second rule you mentioned (one of them is 1), I think any number of them can be 1. bc if I multiply the [20, 50, 36, 42] by the [20, 50, 1, 1], it still gives the same result.

Comment: @jp88 `one of them is 1` represents the comparison of the dimensions of two matrices rather than having only `1` in the same matrix here. `36` and `1` have a `1`, `42` and `1` have a `1` in your example.